# Image link from JSON and apply it to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, dom

I have created a weather app where I collect the data from an API and receive it as JSON file and it is working well, I just have one issue where I want to get the icon from the link in JSON and apply it to my HTML so I can see it myself.

Very basic HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
 
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>weather api</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="data-result"></div>
  <div id="data-result-temp"></div>
  <img id="data-result-icon" src="" alt=""> // I changed this a lot but did not really work.
  
</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

and my JS code here

```
var url = "https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=1a4795e3c8a64d0ba4b92322202711&q=Istanbul";

const city = document.querySelector("#data-result");
const temp = document.querySelector("#data-result-temp");
const icon = document.querySelector("#data-result-icon");
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.onload = function(data, status) {
  const response = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
  console.log(response);
  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    city.innerHTML = response.location.name;
    temp.innerHTML = response.current.temp_c;
    icon.innerHTML = response.current.condition.icon; // dont really know how to update

  } else {
    /** .. **/
  }
}
xhr.onerror = function(err) { 
  console.log(`Network Error`, err);
};

xhr.send();
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `innerHTML` attribute in the icon element into `src` attribute. Then you can display the icon. Check the below example

```js
var url = "https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=1a4795e3c8a64d0ba4b92322202711&q=Istanbul";

const city = document.querySelector("#data-result");
const temp = document.querySelector("#data-result-temp");
const icon = document.querySelector("#data-result-icon");
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.onload = function(data, status) {
  const response = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
  console.log(response);
  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    city.innerHTML = response.location.name;
    temp.innerHTML = response.current.temp_c;
    icon.src = "https:"+response.current.condition.icon;

  } else {
    /** .. **/
  }
}
xhr.onerror = function(err) { 
  console.log(`Network Error`, err);
};

xhr.send();
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
 
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>weather api</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="data-result"></div>
  <div id="data-result-temp"></div>
  <img id="data-result-icon" src="" alt=""> 
  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am getting this weird error "cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/113.png:1 GET file://cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/113.png net::ERR_INVALID_URL"

Comment: you also need to add "http" `icon.src = 'http:' + response.current.condition.icon;`

Comment: Thanks Rene!! :) and Harshana!

Comment: Thank you @RenéDatenschutz. I updated my answer :)

Comment: Glad I could help  @OnurKaradeniz

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
icon.src = response.current.condition.icon;
```

So you're updating the src of the img rather than innerHTML.

Your current code will just return this:

```
<img id="data-result-icon" src="" alt="">//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/113.png</img>
```